# Distinct Keyword usage in SQL query

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called manuscripts

```
BOOKID  AUTHORID BOOKNAME       GENRE   NOOFCOPIES  AMOUNT
B105    A102     Diagnosis      Journal 500         10000
B102    A102     The Essence... Fiction 110         11000
B106    A102     Clinical Sci.  Educat. 125         18750
B104    A103     Mind Games     Fiction 200         20000
B100    A102     Sublime        Fiction 100         10000
B101    A105     C Programming  Educati 125         18750
B103    A101     Scribe         Journal 500         10000
B107    A101     Clinical Chem. Educat. 125         54646
B108    A103     Clinical Chem. Educat. 125         54646
```

How can I get the AuthorIds who have paid Maximum amount? If i write

```
select distinct a.AuthorId,m.amount 
from Author a,manuscripts m 
where m.amount in (select max(amount) 
                   from manuscripts m 
                   where a.AuthorId=m.AuthorId)
```

Then I am able to get correct output, but if I add bookname then it won't result properly..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 3):

since you haven't mentioned the RDBMS you are using, the query below will almost work RDBS, (*not all*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tablename a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  AuthorID, MAX(Amount) max_amount
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY AuthorID
        ) b ON  a.AuthorID = b.AuthorID AND
                a.Amount = b.max_amount
```

for faster performance, add a compound column `INDEX` on `AuthorID, Amount`

Answer (score 0):

This will show every row where the price is maximum:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM amanuscripts m
WHERE m.amount = (select MAX(amount) FROM manuscripts)
```

This will show every row where the price, for every author, is the maximum:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM manuscripts m
WHERE (m.authorid, m.amount) IN (select authorid, MAX(amount)
                                 FROM manuscripts
                                 GROUP BY authorid)
```

(given the structure of your table above, there's no need to join Author table with Manuscripts table)